# What is the difference between mlpconv and maxout layer?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am reading [Network in Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4400.pdf) paper and I struggle with understanding the terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-layer Perceptron (MLP) is a supervised learning algorithm that learns a function by training on a dataset. 
Ref:https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html

In this article the authors are suggesting mlpconv as a stacked layer with MLPs using convolution NN.  The maxout network on the other hand has different capabilities; it can separate concepts that lie within convex sets unlike the conventional convolutional layers which can only perform linear separation